# C# Поиск файла с известным именем с учетом всех поддиректорий

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

День добрый, помогите написать код. Нужно найти файл (известно его полное имя) с учетом всех поддиректорий.
Вот то, что сделал я, но он не работает! Точнее работает, но он сканирует только папку `Program Files (x86)`, но он не сканирует поддиректории и т.д.

```
string[] findFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)", "Log.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in findFiles)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

Comment: А если сделать в этом каталоге еще один каталог с именем "Log.txt" и положить в него искомый файл?

Comment: мб я глупый, но разве это что-то изменит?)  мне нужно что бы софт искал файл без всяких дом директорий =)

Comment: Ваш код сканирует поддиректории - у меня он вполне находит файл C:\Program Files (x86)\AppInsights\log.txt (при запуске с правами админа, ес-но).

Comment: Вы проверьте для начала. Я подозреваю, что поиск идет строго по маске и маска применяется при поиске в подкаталогах, если подкаталога, удовлетворяющего маске нет - в нем нет и поиска. Если это так - есть типовое решение.

Comment: да и в правду, от имени администратора все ищет...но без него нет. Списбо) Но все же без прав админа никак верно?

Comment: @JoneGreen никак. у меня без прав админа просто падает.

Comment: @JoneGreen, уточните про необходимость прав администратора в вопросе.

Comment: Не нужны никакие админские права для чтения большинства папок в Program Files. Код плохой и только.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну естественно не нужны. Я это и не утверждал. Вот только на первой же попавшейся папке с недостатком прав - падает.

Answer (score 3):

Поддиректории приведённый код сканировать должен. В нём другая проблема - как только он встретит папку, к которой нет доступа, он грохнется и больше ничего сканировать не будет. Пожтому надо самому писать рекурсивный алгоритм и обрабатывать исключения, всязанные с правами доступа.

http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44440
http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread957151.html

Comment: Правда, падает? Тю блин.

Comment: Вот ещё в тему: [How to: Iterate File Directories with the Parallel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477033%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Может стоит перенести код в ответ, а не оставлять ссылки на другие форумы, которые могут умереть?

Comment: @PashaPash, мне кажется, там более ценным является обсуждение, а уж написать рекурсивный обход папок - это не проблема и самому?

Comment: @Qwertiy там обсуждение свелось к тому же, что тут обсуджалось в комментах - падает SearchOption.AllDirectories при нехватке прав. и нормального решения по ссылкам нет. ценности в таких ссылках -никаких, imho.

Comment: @Qwertiy я к тому, что брать чужой коммент, который решил проблему топикастера, гуглить, и писать ответ с двумя первыми попавшимися ссылками, по которым **нет** конкретного решения - это не конструктивно. По поводу "решения" по первой ссылке, на VB с каллбеками я вообще лучше промолчу :(

Comment: "что брать чужой коммент" - что?
"гуглить, и писать ответ с двумя первыми попавшимися ссылками" - неправда. Стоило обратить внимание на моё участие в тех ссылках, прежде чем писать такое.

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, сорри, может я погорячился. тем не менее - если у вас есть решение - его стоило бы привести. По ссылкам только "обсуждение". SO сделан не для обсуждения, а для поиска конкретных ответов на конкретные вопросы. Ответы-ссылки тут не приветствуются - даже в кнопке "тревога" на ответе есть соответствующий пункт. Я же не ставлю тут ссылки на свои ответы на других форумах. хотя их over 9000.

Comment: @PashaPash, ok, позже добавлю код.

Answer (score 3):

Без прав админа поиск скорее всего упадет на одной из папок из-за проблем с правами доступа. Запускайте под админом. Или попробуйте рекурсивный поиск с глушением всех ошибок, [как предложил @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419435/177221). Папки без прав доступа к ним будут пропущены:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateAllFiles(string path, string pattern)
{ 
    IEnumerable<string> files = null;
    try { files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern); }
    catch {}

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files) yield return file;
    }

    IEnumerable<string> directories = null;
    try { directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path); }
    catch { }

    if (directories != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in directories.SelectMany(d => EnumerateAllFiles(d, pattern)))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Запускайте под админом."_ - во-первых, бррррррр... Во-вторых, под админом тоже упадёт, если попадётся System Volume Information.

Comment: @Qwertiy топикастер же искал в C:\Program Files (x86) - там не под адимином вообще нечего делать :)

Comment: Ну читать-то там можно (почти?) всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy а под админом там можно читать все :)

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска файлов и каталогов по различным критериям можно использовать библиотеку FastSearchLibrary.
Полное описание и сценарии использования приведены на GitHub:
https://github.com/VladPVS/FastSearchLibrary

Загрузить библиотеку можно здесь
 https://github.com/VladPVS/FastSearchLibrary/releases

Прошу обратить внимание, что все методы библиотеки обрабатывают UnauthorizedAccessException и ошибок подобного рода при её использовании не возникнет.

Кроме того, за счёт использования многопоточности процесс поиска занимает как минимум в 2 раза меньше по сравнению с однопоточными рекурсивными алгоритмами, по крайнем мере это справедливо для масштабных поисков, например по всем дискам компьютера. Для простых операций поиска по нескольким десяткам директорий целесообразнее использовать однопоточные методы, которые также присутствуют в библиотеке.

Краткий пример использования приведен ниже.

```
using FastSearchLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;   
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace SearchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object locker = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Методы с окончанием Fast используют несколько потоков, что ускоряет операцию масштабных поисков (несколько десятков тысяч каталогов и более), но увеличивает нагрузку на процессор.
            // Методы с окончанием Async не блокируют вызывающий поток, который продолжает выполняться далее.
            // Использование статических методов FileSearcher:
            List<FileInfo> list = FileSearcher.GetFiles(@"C:\Users", (f) => f.Name.Contains("SomeFile"));
            Task<List<FileInfo>> task1 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFastAsync(@"C:\Users", "*.txt");
            var task2 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFastAsync(@"C:\", (f) => f.LastAccessTimeUtc >= new DateTime(2018, 3, 1));

            List<FileInfo> resultFiles1 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) => f.Name.Contains("SomePattern")); 
            List<FileInfo> resultFiles2 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) => f.CreationTime > new DateTime(2018, 1, 10));
            List<FileInfo> resultFiles3 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) =>
            {
                return (f.Extension == ".mp3") && (f.Length > 10485760) && (f.CreationTime > new DateTime(2018, 1, 10));
            });

            // Использование экземпляра класса FileSearcher позволяет получать результаты по мере их нахождения,
            // а также останавливать поиск, не дожидаясь его завершения:
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            FileSearcher searcher = new FileSearcher(@"C:\", (f) => Regex.IsMatch(f.Name, @".*Imagine[\S_]Dragons.*.mp3$"), tokenSource);

            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

            searcher.FilesFound += (sender, arg) => 
            {
                lock (locker) // использовать lock обязательно
                {
                    arg.Files.ForEach((f) =>
                    {
                        files.Add(f);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File location: {f.FullName}, \nCreation.Time: {f.CreationTime}");
                    });

                    if (files.Count >= 10)
                        searcher.StopSearch();
                }
            };

            searcher.SearchCompleted += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                if (arg.IsCanceled)
                    Console.WriteLine("Search stopped.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Search completed.");

                Console.WriteLine($"Quantity of files: {files.Count}");
            };

            var task = searcher.StartSearchAsync();

            task.Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```