# Поиск файлов в директориях

Tags: c#

Необходимо найти все файлы на диске. Есть такой код:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo number = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\");
int count = number.GetFiles().Length;
```

Ищет, но не ищет во всех папках. Пробовал так:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo number = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\");
int count = number.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SearchOption.AllDirectories` будет ронять весь поиск, если к одному из подкаталогов нет доступа. А учитывая, что ты передаёшь корень диска, там гарантированно попадётся System Volume Information и поиск упадёт. В остальном код работоспособный.

Чтобы правильно обработать каталоги, к которым нет доступа, надо вместо передачи этого флага написать рекурсивную функцию, которая будет сама перебирать каталоги и игнорировать (или каким-либо ещё образом обрабатывать) исключения ошибки доступа.

PS: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419435/178988
http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44440
http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread957151.html

Answer (score 2):

Раньше пробовала реализовать рекурсивный поиск в папке; может быть, кусочек моего кода Вам пригодится.

```
    private string directoryPath = @"D:\Папка";

    /* Обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Сканировать". */
    private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mask = "*.sln"; // например, можно любую другую
        DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);            
        try
        {
            // Ищем файлы в корневой директории.
            getFiles(root);
            // Рекурсивный поиск по поддиректориям.
            getChildDirectories(root);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    private void getChildDirectories(DirectoryInfo rootDirectory)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in rootDirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            try
            {
                getFiles(directory);
                getChildDirectories(directory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void getFiles(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory.FullName, mask, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // делаешь что-то хорошее с каждым найденным файлом.
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. `catch (Exception ex)` - это плохо. 2. Лучше было возвращать IEnumerable со списком файлов, а не пихать логику внутрь поиска.

Answer (score 1):

Для целей поиска файлов и каталогов по различным критериям можно использовать следующую библиотеку: https://github.com/VladPVS/FastSearchLibrary/releases
Краткий пример использования библиотеки для поиска файлов приведен ниже.

```
using FastSearchLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;   
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace SearchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object locker = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Методы с окончанием Fast используют несколько потоков, что ускоряет операцию поиска, но увеличивает нагрузку на процессор.
            // Методы с окончанием Async не блокируют вызывающий поток, который продолжает выполняться далее.
            // Использование статических методов FileSearcher:
            var list  = FileSearcher.GetFiles(@"C:\Users", (f) => f.Name.Contains("SomeFile")); 
            var task1 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFastAsync(@"C:\Users", "*.txt");
            var task2 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFastAsync(@"C:\", (f) => f.LastAccessTimeUtc >= new DateTime(2018, 3, 1));

            List<FileInfo> resultFiles1 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) => f.Name.Contains("SomePattern")); 
            List<FileInfo> resultFiles2 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) => f.CreationTime > new DateTime(2018, 1, 10));
            List<FileInfo> resultFiles3 = FileSearcher.GetFilesFast(@"C:\", (f) =>
            {
                return (f.Extension == ".mp3") && (f.Length > 10485760) && (f.CreationTime > new DateTime(2018, 1, 10));
            });

            // Использование экземпляра класса FileSearcher позволяет получать результаты по мере их нахождения,
            // а также останавливать поиск, не дожидаясь его завершения:
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            FileSearcher searcher = new FileSearcher(@"C:\", (f) => Regex.IsMatch(f.Name, @".*Imagine[\S_]Dragons.*.mp3$"), tokenSource);

            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

            searcher.FilesFound += (sender, arg) => 
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    arg.Files.ForEach((f) =>
                    {
                        files.Add(f);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File location: {f.FullName}, \nCreation.Time: {f.CreationTime}");
                    });

                    if (files.Count >= 10)
                        searcher.StopSearch();
                }
            };

            searcher.SearchCompleted += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                if (arg.IsCanceled)
                    Console.WriteLine("Search stopped.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Search completed.");

                Console.WriteLine($"Quantity of files: {files.Count}");
            };

            var task = searcher.StartSearchAsync();

            task.Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Аналогично возможно совершать поиск каталогов, но уже с использованием класса DirectorySearcher.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Одной ссылки для этого недостаточно. Привидите описание библиотеки, пример использования. Изменить ответ можно кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/798121/edit).